# An invalid form control with name=' is not focusable error when running my HTML and JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, html, form-control

My JSP takes the file and type of document from user and displays text fields according to the item selected from drop down list.

i.e. if user selects passport it shows text field for passport to enter the passport number in it with some validation on it.

When user press the submit button file should get uploaded is basic functionality

It showing the:

> An invalid form control with name='' is not focusable

Error in inspect element every time I run it.

It is also showing 2 hidden values.

My code:

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
 pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
  <jsp:include page="UserMaster.jsp" />
  <title>Home</title>
  <div class="breadcumb-area flex-style  black-opacity">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <h2>Home</h2>
          <ul class="d-flex">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>

          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="contact-page-area">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <div class="contact-form">
            <h3>
              <span>Upload docs </span> of yours!
            </h3>
            <form name="myform" action="UploadDocServlet" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
              <div class="row">

                <div class="col-8">
                  <input class="form-control" type="file" name="doc" id="fileType" onclick="myFunction()">
                </div>
                </p>
                <p>
                  <div class="col-6">
                    <select name="docType" id="opts" class="form-control" required="required" onchange="showdv(this,'Aadhar','Pancard','Voting','Passport','License', 'Ration Card' ,'Domicile' ,'Cast Certificate' ,'Birth Certificate' ,'Leaving Certificate');">
                      <option value="">select</option>
                      <option value="Aadhar">Aadhar</option>
                      <option value="Pancard">Pancard</option>
                      <option value="Voting">Voting</option>
                      <option value="Passport">Passport</option>
                      <option value="License">License</option>
                      <option value="Ration Card">Ration Card</option>
                      <option value="Domicile">Domicile</option>
                      <option value="Cast Certificate">Cast Certificate</option>
                      <option value="Birth Certificate">Birth Certificate</option>
                      <option value="Leaving Certificate">Leaving Certificate</option>
                    </select>
                    <br>
                    <div class="col-13">
                      <div id="box" style="display:none;">
                        <input Type="text" id="boxx" minlength="12" maxlength="12"><br>

                        <button type="submit">Upload</button>
                      </div>
                      <div id="aadharbox" style="display:none;">
                        <input Type="text" pattern="\d*" id="boxx1" minlength="12" maxlength="12" required="required"><br>

                        <button type="button">Upload</button>
                      </div>

                      <div id="panbox" style="display:none;">
                        <input Type="text" id="boxx2" minlength="10" maxlength="10" required="required"><br>

                        <button type="submit">Upload</button>
                      </div>

                      <div id="votingbox" style="display:none;">
                        <input Type="text" id="boxx3" minlength="10" maxlength="10" required="required"><br>

                        <button type="submit">Upload</button>
                      </div>

                      <div id="passportbox" style="display:none;">
                        <input Type="text" id="boxx4" minlength="8" maxlength="8" required="required"><br>

                        <button type="submit">Upload</button>
                      </div>

                      <div id="licensebox" style="display:none;">
                        <input Type="text" id="boxx5" minlength="15" maxlength="15" required="required"><br>

                        <button type="submit">Upload</button>
                      </div>

                      <div id="rationbox" style="display:none;">
                        <input Type="text" id="boxx6" minlength="8" maxlength="12" required="required"><br>

                        <button type="submit">Upload</button>
                      </div>

                      <div id="domicilebox" style="display:none;">
                        <input Type="text" id="boxx7" minlength="20" maxlength="20" required="required"><br>

                        <button type="submit">Upload</button>
                      </div>

                      <div id="castbox" style="display:none;">
                        <input Type="text" id="boxx8" minlength="8" maxlength="12" required="required"><br>

                        <button type="submit">Upload</button>
                      </div>

                      <div id="birthbox" style="display:none;">
                        <input Type="text" id="boxx9" minlength="10" maxlength="10" required="required"><br>

                        <button type="submit">Upload</button>
                      </div>

                      <div id="leavingbox" style="display:none;">
                        <input Type="text" id="boxx10" minlength="10" maxlength="10" required="required"><br>

                        <button type="submit">Upload</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- footer-area start -->
  <footer class="footer-area">

    <div class="footer-bottom">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12 copyright">
            <p>
              <!-- Link back to Colorlib can't be removed. Template is licensed under CC BY 3.0. -->
              Copyright &copy;
              <script>
                document.write(new Date().getFullYear());
              </script>
              All rights reserved | This template is made with <i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> by <a href=# target="_blank" class="text-primary">MSPS</a>
              <!-- Link back to Colorlib can't be removed. Template is licensed under CC BY 3.0. -->
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
  <!-- footer-area end -->

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function showdv(obj, id1, id2, id3, id4, id5, id6, id7, id8, id9, id10) {
      txt = obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].text;
      document.getElementById("box").style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById("aadharbox").style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById("panbox").style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById("votingbox").style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById("passportbox").style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById("licensebox").style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById("rationbox").style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById("domicilebox").style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById("castbox").style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById("birthbox").style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById("leavingbox").style.display = 'none';
      if (txt.match(id1)) {
        document.getElementById("aadharbox").style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById("boxx1").placeholder = "Enter Aadhar Number"
      }
      if (txt.match(id2)) {
        document.getElementById("panbox").style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById("boxx2").placeholder = "Enter Pan Number"
      }
      if (txt.match(id3)) {
        document.getElementById("votingbox").style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById("boxx3").placeholder = "Enter Voting ID"
      }
      if (txt.match(id4)) {
        document.getElementById("passportbox").style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById("boxx4").placeholder = "Enter Passport Number"
      }
      if (txt.match(id5)) {
        document.getElementById("licensebox").style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById("boxx5").placeholder = "Enter License Number"
      }
      if (txt.match(id6)) {
        document.getElementById("rationbox").style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById("boxx6").placeholder = "Enter Ration Card Number"
      }
      if (txt.match(id7)) {
        document.getElementById("domicilebox").style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById("boxx7").placeholder = "Enter Domicile Number"
      }
      if (txt.match(id8)) {
        document.getElementById("castbox").style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById("boxx8").placeholder = "Enter Case Certificate Number"
      }
      if (txt.match(id9)) {
        document.getElementById("birthbox").style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById("boxx9").placeholder = "Enter Birth Certificate Number"
      }
      if (txt.match(id10)) {
        document.getElementById("leavingbox").style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById("boxx10").placeholder = "Enter Leaving Certificate Number"
      }
    }

    function myFunction() {
      document.getElementById("fileType").onchange = function() {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        var fileName = this.value;
        var fileExtension = fileName.substr(fileName.length - 5);
        var fileExtensionNew = fileName.substr(fileName.length - 4);

        if (fileExtensionNew != ".png" && fileExtensionNew != ".jpg" && fileExtension != ".jpeg") {
          alert("Invalid File Type. Please select Image only");
          $("#fileType").attr("src", "blank");

          $('#fileType').wrap('<form>').closest('form').get(0).reset();
          $('#fileType').unwrap();
          return false;
        }

        reader.onload = function(e) {
          // get loaded data and render thumbnail.
          document.getElementById("fileType").src = e.target.result;
          $("#fileType").show();
        };

        // read the image file as a data URL.
        reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
      };
    }
  </script>

  <!-- jquery latest version -->
  <script src="assets/js/vendor/jquery-2.2.4.min.js "></script>
  <!-- popper.min.js -->
  <script src="assets/js/vendor/popper.min.js "></script>
  <!-- bootstrap js -->
  <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js "></script>
  <!-- owl.carousel.2.0.0-beta.2.4 css -->
  <script src="assets/js/owl.carousel.min.js "></script>
  <!-- swiper.min.js -->
  <script src="assets/js/swiper.min.js "></script>
  <!-- mailchimp.js -->
  <script src="assets/js/mailchimp.js"></script>
  <!-- metisMenu.min.js -->
  <script src="assets/js/metisMenu.min.js"></script>
  <!-- plugins js -->
  <script src="assets/js/plugins.js "></script>
  <!-- google map -->

  <!-- main js -->
  <script src="assets/js/scripts.js "></script>
  </body>

  </html>
```

Comment: Try editing your code down to a small file that reproduces the error, instead of pasting your entire project here. This will not only help people answer your question, but when you are looking at just a small section of relevant code, you are more likely to notice the problem!

Comment: hello sir, but the code is not showing any errors but it is not submitting form in url

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple examples like:

```
<div id="panbox" style="display:none;">
    <input Type="text" id="boxx2" minlength="10" maxlength="10" required="required"><br>
   <button type="submit">Upload</button>
</div>
```

The input is `required` so the form **can't** be submitted unless it is filled in.

However, it is inside an element with `style="display:none;"` so the browser isn't showing it, so the user **can't** fill it in.

> My JSP takes the file and type of document from user and displays text fields according to the item selected from drop down list.

If you are making decisions about which fields are shown based on the selection, then probably you should be making decisions about which ones are **required** at the same time.

Comment: it is showing the file selector at first and if user selects file and selects the type of document from drop-down the based on that it show user text-field which user fills and clicks on submit,boom nothing happening.

Comment: @ShubhamKadam — That is because, as I said in my answer, of **all the other required but invisible fields**.

Comment: so how can I tackle the problem? and how do i pass hidden values?

Comment: @ShubhamKadam — I refer you back to the last paragraph in my answer.

Comment: okay sir but i am unable to do that, can u please guide me how can i make decision about which one is required at time

Answer (score 1):

in some cases, this problem appears despite the input is **not required**,

because there is `value="some_value"` in the html input.

if we change it to `value=""` it will be submitted.